# Bitlocker suddenly activated on my machine, prompting for recovery key that I don't have

Tags: windows-10, encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker

I've run into a very strange problem with my Lenovo laptop (Windows 10 Home) and although people say it's not possible, it still happened.

I have been using my laptop for over two years and have not enabled bitlocker. My machine is not registered to a domain. At startup I always enter the password for my local windows account. I also haven't linked my Microsoft Account, so I looked for the saved recovery key, but it's not there.

One thing that happened recently was that my integrated camera stopped working and I updated the firmware. Shortly after it appears my laptop crashed and after a system shutdown my machine entered into the BitLocker recovery mode with the following message:

"**Enter the recovery key for this drive.
You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed.**"

Like I mentioned, I have never enabled BitLocker on my machine itself, and therefore I do not have a recovery key.

Whenever I run manage-bde -status I get the results below. A lot is marked as '*Unknown*', but I don't know if that means anything.

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.19041
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: [Label Unknown]
[Data Volume]

    Size:                 Unknown GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Unknown
    Percentage Encrypted: Unknown%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Unknown
    Lock Status:          Locked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
    Key Protectors:       Numerical Password | TPM
```

**Question:**
Is there any way to still be able to get access to my data?

Comment: Is this Windows Home or Pro? Have you ever had a Microsoft Account linked to the system?

Comment: “Is there any way to still be able to get access to my data?” -  Without the BitLocker Recovery key data recovery is impossible. That status of BitLocker is odd, it’s almost like the encryption process was started but never finished

Comment: Could be related to drive failure or malware or something else. Boot from USB, check disk status, try to access and save data. Best bet is restore from last full disk image.

Comment: I think @DrMoishePippik is the most likely scenario here. Ramhound is correct: with bitlocker enabled your data is gone unless you have that key. As encryption may be only partially completed, you may be able to perform recovery on the drive and recover data from the portions not yet encrypted.

Comment: In order to help us better understand how this may have happened, is there anything else that happened on the system leading up to this happening? Anything at all?

Comment: Thanks all. I actually came across this thread on the Dell forum where people have faced a similar problem after a BIOS update. They seems to have gone through the similar route of booting from flash drive and downgrading the BIOS. Not sure if I'm allowed to post the link, but here's the thread [link](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/xps/xps-13-9360-asks-for-bitlocker-after-update/647f95d0f4ccf8a8de86ac93?commentId=647f9642f4ccf8a8de902b9d#M89422). Will try to boot from USB and see if it works.

Comment: @music2myear I do remember also being prompted for a BIOS update a couple of days before, but only after an overnight reboot I ended up in the BitLocker recovery mode. This supports the claim that other people have experienced on other brands. But what's even more weird to me is that I have Windows 10 Home edition and according to Microsoft BitLocker isn't available there. So far I have tried to downgrade the BIOS, but no luck so far unfortunately.